# Debian: Simple way to compress files wanted

Tags: debian, compression, tar

I often need to compress archives in Linux. is there a simpler way instead of always building such complicated commands?

```
tar zcvf /tmp/mybackup.tar.gz /home/important
```

Comment: Like, creating an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias would mean you don't have to remember the `zcvf` options. You can name the alias whatever you want as long as it is one word.

Create the alias in your terminal with

```
alias archive='tar zcvf'
```

and then your command becomes

```
archive /tmp/mybackup.tar.gz /home/important
```

If you like this alias, make it permanent by adding it to your `~/.bashrc`. (Or whatever config file is sourced by the shell you are using.) Then every new terminal you open will have the alias already configured and ready to use.

Comment: A suggestion: use `acvpf` flags instead, so tar will determine a stream compressor from the file extension, and also to preserve permissions. The same alias would work for any archive type: `archive backup.tar.xz /files /to /backup` will commress with `xz`, while `archive anotherbackup.tar.zst /different /files` will use `zstd`. `gzip`, `bzip2`, `lzo` — all of them will work.

Comment: Good idea @NikitaKipriyanov!